# Extracting "World Reference Base (2006) Soil Groups" data in R and searching for the legend of the extracted values

Tags: legend, soilgrids

I downloaded the "World Reference Base (2006) Soil Groups" data per the SoilGrid website as tile1 and processed the data in R (xmin = -116, xmax = -114, ymin = 30, ymax = 32):

```
### Soil properties of the localities
soil = raster("C:/Users/Besitzer/Documents/MEP/data/soil/tile1.tif")
example_Test@data$soil = raster::extract(soil, example_Test)
```

I obtained the following values (> example_Test):

```
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 24 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[37] NA NA NA NA 24 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  4 NA NA NA NA NA 24  4 NA 24 24  4 NA NA NA NA
```

I expected values like: HS or AT or TC. Where do I find a key on how to interpret the extracted numbers? --> 4, 24, see above

Answer (score 1):

If necessary the full soilgrids data can be found [here](https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/).

In general the geotiff created on the WCS/soilgrids website, don't have an internal RAT table (it is a know issue). The legends are in a separated folder on the repository:  https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data/wrb/MostProbable.rat.xml

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jorge. If I may add a question:

Comment: In the "World reference base for soil resources 2014, 2015 Update", there are lists of the soil types. I prepared a translation table as a quick reference.

Comment: In the link you provided, Albeluvisols are listed with ID = 1, but they are not listed in the "World reference base". Furthermore, the "World reference base" lists Anthrosols (AT), Technosols (TC), and Retisols (RT), which are not listed in the link you provided. Are they not synced or is the discrepancy only due to updates in nomenclature or knowledge? Thanks again.

Comment: On the soilgrids [FAQ](https://www.isric.org/explore/soilgrids/faq-soilgrids) you have a section concerning soil groups on soilgrids, give it a look

Answer (score 0):

Just load a WRB tif into QGIS, use the "set layer style" tool, and load the WRB style symbology from https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/legends/, and finally in QGIS, the categorical legend will be loaded into your WRB tif. However, you can export the values of your WRB tiff associated with the categories in layer properties > symbology > advanced options [...] (click here) and the option to export map to file will appear. In the resulting file, you can easily associate the soil value of the tiff with the categorical variable.[image]